# Returning unknown variable in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to return an object in a model's view that goes an element and I can't figure out how to get my conditions out properly. Here's my controller:

```
    function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid admission', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
            $admission = $this->Admission->read(null, $id);

            **$_patient_id = 2;**
            $patientAdmissions = $this->Admission->getCurrentPatientAdmissions($_patient_id);

    $this->set(compact('admission', 'patientAdmissions'));
}
```

This view function is in the admissions_controller and shows a specific admission with $id. I want to display a div with all of this patient's admissions in it. My getCurrentPatientAdmissions looks like this:

```
    function getCurrentPatientAdmissions($_patient_id) {
      $params = array(
          'conditions' => array(
              'Admission.patient_id' => $_patient_id,
          ),
      );
      return $this->find('all', $params);
    }
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you placing the 'getCurrentPatientAdmissions' function? what file?

Why are you using the function 'getCurrentPatientAddmissions' instead of just running 'find'?

```
$patientAdmissions = $this->Admissions->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Admission.patient_id' => $admission['Patient']['id']
   )
  )
);
```

It seems like creating a function for something as simple as this is a bit over kill...

Doesn't the read function:

```
$admission = $this->Admission->read(null, $id);
```

already get a list of all the patients addmissions for you?

Comment: @YonoRan Bother are in admissions model

Comment: @YonoRan No it doesn't. This is the admissions view which shows specific admissions. I want to show the other admissions for the patient in that view so they can select other admissions. I want to keep it in this view because it will show admission specific data (events, comments, etc) related to the admission.

Comment: You have 2 models with the same name? cause in both cases your running a query on the admissions model. What exactly is the structure and relationships?

Comment: Patients, Floors top level, then Admissions, Then Events, Comments, Followups;  A patient can have multiple admissions, each admission can have multiple events comments and followups

Comment: At the moment, we're talking about the Admissions->View Controller which calls a couple Model Classes. There probably is a better way to do it

Comment: Solved it. I'll post it in a sec.

Comment: so basically: Patients - hasMany Admissions, Admissions hasMany what ever. You want to get all the Patients admissions. If you create the relationships between the tables properly (define that a patient hasMany Admission in the patients model) and ther recursive variable is set to 1 or 2 (higher than 0) than cakePHP will fetch all the Admissions for a selected patient automatically. you wont need the extra query.

Comment: @YonoRan Won't let me answer it. How would that work if I'm within a specific Admission. So localhost/admissions/view/3 where 3 is the Admission Id.  It is only returning the data for Admission 3 in the array

Comment: but if Admission belongsTo patient than when you get the admissions information (by using the specific admission id) you should also get all the patient information - so just query for a list of all the specific patients admissions: `$patientAdmissions = $this->Admissions->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Admission.patient_id' => $id)));` your already working in the admissions model, you already have the patient id (from the read query)...

Comment: yes... but because admission belongTo Patient the result should also have the patient id in it (the patient that the admission belongs to) so you can get the patient id out of the result and run another query, like the one I specified in the comment above.

Comment: Guess it does seem like I went around my elbow to get to my thumb now. That works too tho the conditional is: 'Admission.patient_id' => $admission['Patient']['id']. Hah. Thanks @YonoRan. Time to clean up some crappy code